# Probability of intersection of events for beta random variables

Tags: probability

Consider a collection of random variables $X_k$, $k=1,\ldots,n$, that are each distributed according to the beta distribution, that is, $X_k\sim\text{Beta}(\alpha_k,\beta_k)$.

How do I write the probability 
\begin{align*}
P\left(\bigcap_{k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}}\{X_k\ge a\}\right)
\end{align*}
in terms of $(\alpha_k,\beta_k)$, $k=1,\ldots,n$, and $a$?

---

**Attempt:** I know that if we wanted to write $P(X\ge a)$ where $X\sim\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ then we could just use the CDF of the beta distribution, termed the regularized incomplete beta function and denoted by $I_x(\alpha,\beta)$ (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)), to get
\begin{align*}
P(X\ge a) = I_{a}(\alpha,\beta)
\end{align*}
I think this is correct (please let me know if it is not). How would we go about applying a similar idea to the intersection event defined above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the random variables are independent, then the probability is $\prod_{k=1}^n P(X_k \ge a)$.